# Expose app on Azure VM domain name with Ingress

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have deployed the WeaveSocks sample app on a manually installed kubeadm that is hosted on a VM (Ubuntu 20.04) on Azure (educational purpose).

I want now the app to be able on the VM domain name : <name>.switzerlandnorth.cloudapp.azure.com

Here is what I have :

**Deploy the app**

```
kubectl create namespace sock-shop
kubectl apply -n sock-shop -f "https://github.com/microservices-demo/microservices-demo/blob/master/deploy/kubernetes/complete-demo.yaml?raw=true"

kubectl -n sock-shop get svc front-end
NAME        TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
front-end   NodePort   10.98.85.243   <none>        80:30001/TCP   43m
```

**Ingress Controller**

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

**Ingress** 
`ingress.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sock-shop
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "<name>.switzerlandnorth.cloudapp.azure.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: sock-shop
            port:
              number: 80
```

```
kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
```

**Some commands that may be useful**

```
kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.100.216.61    <pending>     80:30460/TCP,443:31272/TCP   53m
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.97.67.150     <none>        443/TCP                      53m
```

```
kubectl describe service -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller
Name:                     ingress-nginx-controller
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                          app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=1.1.1
                          helm.sh/chart=ingress-nginx-4.0.15
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.100.216.61
IPs:                      10.100.216.61
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30460/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.205.198:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31272/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.205.198:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Local
HealthCheck NodePort:     30942
Events:                   <none>
```

With this I'm unable to go to http://<name>.switzerlandnorth.cloudapp.azure.com and see my app.

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT** I've done a `telnet \<name\>.switzerlandnorth.cloudapp.azure.com 80` and it can't connect to port 80. So it seems that the Ingress is not listening at all on the port 80 of the host.

Comment: `<name>` in `host` is specified as `foo.switzerlandnorth.cloudapp.azure.com`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can modify configuration about your **hosts** (/etc/hosts) file to make sure your computer can resolve this domain name.
Use NAT mode in your VM config, and find VM's ip to add the entry to **hosts**.